# Event Handlers not throwing alerts (html, JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, dom-events

I'm trying to learn simple event handling in html. I have created a few fields that need data entered. As you can see from the code, my intention is that the numbers are restricted to a certain range. For some reason when I enter values outside of these ranges, my alerts are not going off. If anyone could steer me in the right direction that would be great.

HTML File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script_5.7.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h3>User Information</h3>
<form action="">
    <p>
        <label>
            Age:
            <input type="text" id="theAge"/>
        </label>
        <br/><br/>

        <label>
            Weight:
            <input type="text" id="theWeight"/>
        </label>
        <br/><br/>

        <input type="submit" id="submit"/>
    </p>
    </form>
<script type="text" src="script2_5.7.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

first js file:

```
function chkAge() {
    var theAge = document.getElementById("custAge");

    if (theAge < 17 || theAge > 80) {
        alert("Please Enter a Valid Age!");
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
    }

function chkWeight() {
    var theWeight = document.getElementById("custWeight");
    if (theWeight < 80 || theWeight > 300) {
        alert("Please Enter a Valid Age!");
        return false;
    }
    else
    return true;
    }
```

second js file:

```
document.getElementById("theAge").onsubmit = chkAge;
document.getElementById("theWeight").onsubmit = chkWeight;
```

Comment: your html form does not even have a action on it to fire your functions?

Comment: I see what you mean now. I was following an example from an old textbook and didn't realize the role of form action. Is that where they will always be fired?

Comment: see my answer i have fixed it for you

Comment: Well, you had multiple errors, but all of them are solved in comments. Check them all!

Answer (score 0):

```
function chkAge() {
    var theAge = document.getElementById("custAge");


    if (theAge.value < 17 || theAge.value > 80) {
        alert("Please Enter a Valid Age!");
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
    }

function chkWeight() {
    var theWeight = document.getElementById("custWeight");
    if (theWeight.value < 80 || theWeight.value > 300) {
        alert("Please Enter a Valid Age!");
        return false;
    }
    else
    return true;
    }
```

Check if this helps.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp also,check this tutorial.
DOM form elements !== their values.

Answer (score 0):

You did not have a click event on your form when it was submitted therefore your functions were never being called.. Also when getting a value using javascript you have to use the `.value` element..  try the below:

```js
function handleClick(){
  chkAge();
  chkWeight();
}

function chkAge() {
    var theAge = document.getElementById("theAge").value;

    if (theAge < 17 || theAge > 80) {
        alert("Please Enter a Valid Age!");
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
    }

function chkWeight() {
    var theWeight = document.getElementById("theWeight").value;
    if (theWeight < 80 || theWeight > 300) {
        alert("Please Enter a Valid weight!");
        return false;
    }
    else
    return true;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script_5.7.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h3>User Information</h3>
<form action="" onSubmit="return handleClick()">
    <p>
        <label>
            Age:
            <input type="text" id="theAge"/>
        </label>
        <br/><br/>

        <label>
            Weight:
            <input type="text" id="theWeight"/>
        </label>
        <br/><br/>

        <input type="submit" id="submit"/>
    </p>
    </form>
<script type="text" src="script2_5.7.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I ran the code snippet and also adjusted my code to match yours. For some reason the alert is thrown every time now.

Comment: it doesnt try again.. if i enter say 25 in the age and 834231 in the weight on the age only the weight alert will show etc.. so works as you would want it too...

Answer (score 0):

The functions you have are not being called. chkAge and chkWeight on the second js file need ().

```
document.getElementById("theAge").onsubmit = chkAge();
document.getElementById("theWeight").onsubmit = chkWeight();
```

You could also just call the functions with a button to test them out

```
<button onclick="chkAge()">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

To test the value of your two input boxes on submit you first need to store the value of those boxes on the js so your conditional statements have something to check. You're attempting to do this with your **theAge** and **theWeight** variables however these are returning undefined as the id selector **chkAge** and **chkWeight** doesn't exist on your html.

In addition for the purposes of semantic html, your **label** tags need to be a separate element to your **input** tags which also need a **value** attribute so you can target and store something on your js to check.

I've rewritten your code as a working example targeting theAge and theWeight input **value** attributes, removing the **p** tag wrapper and giving your form an **id** for the **event listener**:

```js
function checkDetails(event) {
  
  var theAge = document.getElementById("theAge").value,
      theWeight = document.getElementById("theAge").value;
  
    if (theAge < 17 || theAge > 80) {
      event.preventDefault();
      alert("Please Enter a Valid Age!");
    }
  
    if (theWeight < 80 || theWeight > 300) {
      event.preventDefault();
      alert("Please Enter a Valid Weight!");
    }
}
  

document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", checkDetails);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h3>User Information</h3>
  <form id="myForm" action="">
    <p>
      <label for="theAge">Age:</label>
      <input type="text" id="theAge" value=""/>

      <br/><br/>

      <label>Weight:</label>
      <input type="text" id="theWeight" value=""/>

      <br/><br/>

      <input type="submit" id="submit"/>
    </p>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Working js bin link - https://jsbin.com/jiyibuwexi/edit?html,js